# Circular dependency error but type required for method?

Tags: c++, include, dependencies, circular-dependency

Edit: I believe this question is not a copy of "resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies" and I would still like this one answered because I have difficulty understanding "resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies".

I have a small problem while I am trying to connect three classes together. The relation between them is made by a function that is called `void LinkMachine(...)`. Pointers are used.

This is my first Class:

```
#pragma once

#include "SFML\Graphics.hpp"
#include <vector>

#include "threader.h"
#include "resourceManager.h"

#include "entity.h"
#include "text.h"
#include "tile.h"
#include "monster.h"

class t_entityManager
{
private:

    t_resourceManager* m_Resource_Manager;
    t_threader* m_Threader;

    std::vector<std::vector<t_entity*>> m_TileMap;
    std::vector<t_monster*> m_MonsterList;
    std::vector<t_text*> m_GUIList;

    //Work on this part
    sf::Sprite* m_Background;
    t_entity* m_Hovered;
    t_entity* m_Clicked;

public:
    t_entityManager();
    ~t_entityManager();

    void LinkMachine(t_resourceManager* resource, t_threader* threader);

    void RefreshAll(sf::RenderWindow* window);

    void ProjectCast(sf::Vector2i rayCoord);
    bool CalculateCast(sf::Vector2i mouseCoord, sf::Vector2f entityCoord, sf::Vector2f entitySize);

    void CreateMap();

    std::string WatchClick();

    void ResetAll();

    void MakeText(std::string gameState);
    void MakeTurret(sf::Vector2i position);
    void MakeMonster(int type);

    void DrawAll(sf::RenderWindow* window);
};
```

This is my second class:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\Window.hpp>

#include "entityManager.h"
//This class is only a class to make side-thread that we can link using a pointer.

//Thread ID
//User_Input : 1

class t_threader
{
private:
    sf::RenderWindow* m_Window;
    t_entityManager* m_Entity_Manager;

    sf::Vector2i m_Mouse_Coord;
    bool m_Clicked;

    sf::Thread* m_Thread_UserInput;

public:
    t_threader(sf::RenderWindow* window);
    ~t_threader(void);

    void LinkMachine(t_entityManager* entity);
    //Not really useful but could be useful.
    void LinkWindow(sf::RenderWindow* window);

    void StartThread(int thread_ID);

    void UserInput();

    sf::Vector2i GetCoord();
    bool GetClick();

};
```

The error that I receive at compile time talks about **circular dependencies**. Anyway, I need all the calls to the `LinkMachine()` to accomplish my task.

The obtained error is:

```
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 't_entityManager'    c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 27  1   AvZ

Error   10  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 't_entityManager'    c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 27  1   AvZ

Error   16  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 't_entityManager'    c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 27  1   AvZ

Error   21  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 't_entityManager'    c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 27  1   AvZ

Error   27  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 't_entityManager'    c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 27  1   AvZ

Error   6   error C2065: 'entity' : undeclared identifier   
c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.cpp   22  1   AvZ

Error   4   error C2065: 'm_Entity_Manager' : undeclared identifier c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.cpp   7   1   AvZ

Error   5   error C2065: 't_entityManager' : undeclared identifier  c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.cpp   22  1   AvZ

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   8   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   14  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   19  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   25  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   7   error C2448: 't_threader::LinkMachine' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.cpp   23  1   AvZ

Error   24  error C2660: 't_threader::LinkMachine' : function does not take 1 arguments c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\gamemanager.cpp    40  1   AvZ

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   9   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   15  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   20  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ

Error   26  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\gabriel\desktop\avz\avz\threader.h 16  1   AvZ
```

Comment: Oh, and if anybody has a good book which explains how to properly use headers, please share it !!! I know my headers are really bad and I really want to learn how to make proper ones. Thank you

Comment: If you don't need to know the content of a structure/class, you can just declare it with `class t_resourceManager;` instead of including its header. The basic rule to know whether an header file should include another header file is ownership. If at least one class of entityManager.h like `t_entityManager` has the ownership on another class of `resourceManager.h`, then it should include it.